# httpRequest.getSession(true) method returns null in weblogic

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, weblogic, weblogic12c

As the JavaDoc of httpRequest.getSession(true) method clearly states that this method will always return a session. But when I am running this application in weblogic_12.1.3, I am getting "null" from this method. I debugged it and found out that it is returning null from wlfulclient.jar. Not sure what I am missing. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The WebLogic full client `wlfullclient.jar` is **deprecated** as of **WebLogic Server 12.1.3** and may be removed in a future release. Oracle recommends using the WebLogic Thin T3 client(`wlthint3client.jar`) or other appropriate client depending on your environment.

The WebLogic Thin T3 Client jar (`wlthint3client.jar`) is a light-weight, high performing alternative to the `wlfullclient.jar` and `wlclient.jar` (`IIOP`) remote client jars. The Thin T3 client has a minimal footprint while providing access to a rich set of APIs that are appropriate for client usage. As its name implies, the Thin T3 Client uses the WebLogic T3 protocol, which provides significant performance improvements over the `wlclient.jar`, which uses the `IIOP` protocol.

> Oracle WebLogic's T3/T3S protocol for Remote Method Invocation (RMI),
>   including: RMI over HTTP (HTTP tunneling) and RMI over HTTPS (HTTP
>   Tunneling over SSL). For more information on WebLogic T3
>   communication, see [Using WebLogic RMI with T3 Protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLRMI/rmi_t3.htm#WLRMI143) in
>   Developing RMI Applications for Oracle WebLogic Server.